# Storing a Big Number in a Variable and Looping

Tags: c++, c

How can i store a big number in a variable and use a for loop?
I have a very big number `75472202764752234070123900087933251` and i need to loop from 0 to this number!
Is it even possible to do this? how much time will it take to end?

**EDIT:** i am trying to solve a hard problem by brute force. its a combination problem.the bruteforcing cases may reach 470C450.
so i guess i should use a different algorithm...

Comment: That's one of the terms in Pascal's triangle. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Jared Ng - That you recognize that is a little creepy, please tell me you googled it or something

Comment: "I need to loop"... what for? What are you going to do each time through the loop?

Comment: Forget it. You'll wait like billions of billions of years for the program to end. Probably the algorithm of your choice (that implies iterating such a loop) is inappropriate.

Comment: With regards to your future questions (and edits on this one), are you using C or C++? They are not the same language, and answers that are good for one will be bad practice (or not even valid) for the other.

Comment: @Chris Isn't "will be" a little strongly worded?

Comment: @shelleybutterfly - No. `(int *)malloc(10 * sizeof int)` is bad practice in C++ (C-style casts are bad in C++, it should use `static_cast<int *>`) and C (casting `void *` reduces maintainability and can hide errors for failing to include `stdlib.h`). Trying to write in both produces code that is bad for both, with no benefit (what platform has a C++ compiler and not a C compiler? And what benefits will you get if say it's in C++ but don't use any C++ features?)

Comment: I can come up with plenty of cases myself, but "will be" implies there are no counterexamples, therefore "will be" is simply incorrect. e.g. Q:'What expression can I use to find the index of <x,y> in a 1D array that stores a 2D row-major array with stride S?' A:'y*S + x'.

Answer (score 4):

This might take 
0.23 x 10^23 years if C++ processed 100,000 loops per second :|

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=75472202764752234070123900087933251%2F%28100000*1*3600*24*365%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=75472202764752234070123900087933251/%28100000%2a1%2a3600%2a24%2a365%29)

Comment: I don't think 0.XX x 10^XX isn't correct scientific notation. Use 2.3 x 10^22. =P

Comment: LOL! And the answer would be 42.

Comment: @chris , yes agreed, I just pasted what wolframalpha showed me.It is skynet making us dumber day by day .

Answer (score 2):

Well, you would need an implementation that can handle at least a subset of the initialization, boolean, and arithmetic functions on very large integers. Something like: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/.

For something that would give a bit better performance than a general large integer math library, you could use specialized operations specifically to allow use of a large integer as a counter. For an example of this, see [dewtell's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7048266/revisions) to this question.

As for it being possible for you to loop from 0 to that number: well, yes, it is possible to write the code for it with one of the above solutions, but I think the answer is no, you personally will not be able to do it because you will not be alive to see it finish.

[edit: Yes, I would definitely recommend you find a different algorithm. :D]

Answer (score 2):

It looks that this number fits into 128 bit. So you could use a modern system and a modern compiler that implements such numbers. This would e.g be the case for a 64bit linux system with gcc as a compiler. This has something like `__uint128_t` that you could use.

Obviously you can't use such a variable as a `for`-loop variable, others have give you the calculations. But you could use it to store some of your calculations.

Comment: Only thing is that you might want to typedef that `__uint128_t` away so you can use the code on multiple systems,  changing in one place

Comment: Why is it defined as `__uint128_t` (with double underscores)? Isn't the point of `stdint.h` that a system defines them _if they exist_? Why use double underscores like it's a nonstandard extention?

Comment: @Schnommus - And how would that `typedef` handle operators and such? Or are we assuming the OP wants C++ (he lists both C and C++ so I'm assuming he means the one I like better :P )

Comment: @Chris Lutz - I'm assuming C++ (usually when tagged both, C++ is meant). Overloading operators you could achieve similar behaviour no matter what underlying datatype you use.

Comment: @Schnommus - Usually they mean C++. Sometimes they're C newbies who've been told that C and C++ are basically the same, so they conflate the two. (I wonder if there's a way to use the SO database to get the percentages of questions tagged C and C++ that get retagged to one or the other...)

Comment: @Chris, this type is not an "extended integer type" in the sense of the standard but an extension of the C standard by the compiler. (Note the subtle difference :) They can't include this as an extended type because then they would have to change `uintmax_t` to it and have the library support the type, too, in particular `printf` and friends.

Comment: @Jens - So basically "because it would be more work to support it the way it should be supported?" (I think they probably _should_ change `uintmax_t` since `__uint128_t` would be the biggest integral type supported. And what's the point of providing a "native" (works with operators in C) integral type if you don't provide `printf` support for it?)

Comment: @Chris, changing `uintmax_t` has a lot of implications. You can't do that in a rush, you would get binary incompatibilities all over the place. Basically you'd have to change the machine model of the system. For `printf`, it is not so difficult to write an output function for that. The basic operations `+`, `<<` etc seem to be supported. What I forgot, among the things to change would also be the preprocessor, this is supposed to compute in `[u]intmax_t`. So at the moment you also can't write constants of that type, you have to combine them as in `((__uint128_t)x << 64)|((__uint128_t)y)`.

Comment: @Jens - Ah! There's the part that causes the problems. (My point about `printf` is less "how do I print it?" and more "but I wanna print it with `printf` waaah!")

Answer (score 1):

If you need to loop a certain number of times, and that number is greater than 2^64, just use `while(1)` because your computer will break before it counts up to 2^64 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a complete bignum package - if all you need is a loop counter, here's a simple byte counter that uses an array of bytes as a counter.  It stops when the byte array wraps around to all zeros again.  If you wanted to count to some other value than 2^(bytesUsed*CHAR_BITS), you could just compute the two's complement value of the negative of the number of iterations you wanted, and let it count up to 0, keeping in mind that bytes[0] is the low-order byte (or use the positive value and count down instead of up).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXBYTES 20
/* Simple byte counter - note it uses argc as # of bytes to use for convenience */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char bytes[MAXBYTES];
    const int bytesUsed = argc < MAXBYTES? argc : MAXBYTES;
    int i;
    unsigned long counter = (unsigned long)-1; /* to give loop something to do */
    for (i = 0; i < bytesUsed; i++) bytes[i] = 0; /* Initialize bytes */
    do {
        for (i = 0; i < bytesUsed && !++bytes[i]; i++) ; /* NULL BODY - this is the byte counter */
        counter++;
    } while (i < bytesUsed);
    printf("With %d bytes used, final counter value = %lu\n", bytesUsed, counter);
}
```

Run times for the first 4 values (under Cygwin, on a Lenovo T61):

$ time ./bytecounter

With 1 bytes used, final counter value = 255

real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./bytecounter a

With 2 bytes used, final counter value = 65535

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.031s

$ time ./bytecounter a a

With 3 bytes used, final counter value = 16777215

real    0m0.125s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./bytecounter a a a

With 4 bytes used, final counter value = 4294967295

real    0m6.578s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.047s

At this rate, five bytes should take around half an hour, and six bytes should take the better part of a week.  Of course the counter value will be inaccurate for those - it's mostly just there to verify the number of iterations for the smaller byte values and give the loop something to do.

Edit: And here's the time for five bytes, around half an hour as I predicted:

$ time ./bytecounter a a a a

With 5 bytes used, final counter value = 4294967295

real    27m22.184s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.062s

Comment: While true that you don't need all the functionality provided by a big number package, to meet the requirements of creating a loop with [huge number] iterations, you would still need a sufficient subset of these functions: { initialize a huge number (hn) variable to a specified hn, negate a hn var, increment a hn var by 1, decrement a hn var by 1, compare a hn var to 0, compare a hn var to a hn (or hn var) }.  And once you've done all that, you might as well just use an existing tested library. Library functions you don't use don't cost you anything, but writing new ones takes time and risk.

Comment: Everything except the initialize and negate is basically already in that little program above.  The increment/decrement and compare to 0 is all in that one line loop with the empty body (change the ++bytes[i] to --bytes[i] to decrement).  Figuring out the value to initialize to can be done offline, using a tool that includes a bignum package if necessary - it doesn't need to be part of your program unless you want it to be.  The point is that the functionality you need for a loop counter is quite simple.

Comment: Ok, you should make it bytes[i]-- to decrement, and it then compares to -1 rather than 0 at the end.  Still pretty simple, and it will probably run quite a bit faster than a general-purpose bignum calculation precisely because it doesn't need all the general-purpose overhead that comes along with the package.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're getting at; I was reluctant to assume the offline calculation, but, fair enough, just include the big int package and then use it to initialize the counter bytes.  So, say we want to initialize to the big number, then count down to zero as per your suggestion... It doesn't look like the code as it stands handles any cases other than the powers of 2 though; although I was still verifying that and didn't mean to post yet. :P

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong I think; would you be willing to revise your code to mention the static or bignum init (comment seems appropriate) and to do the count down to zero? that way it shows how to do it for other than powers of 2. +1 for giving code for a simple way to be more efficient

Comment: Working on it.  Watch this space for more details later.  Also going to add an efficiency boost by increasing the size of the counter elements once counting to an arbitrary num is in there.

Comment: Nice! Also, using a countdown, you can make bytesUsed into a variable and decrement it each time the current most significant byte goes to 0. For smaller numbers this won't make a huge difference, but the added checks become more and more weighted for each significant byte you had to start with.  e.g. If i have my math right, you'd save 2^8 checks for a 2-byte count, 2^16 + 2^8 checks for a 3-byte count, 2^24 + 2^16 + 2^8 checks for a 4-byte count and so forth. Over the course of a loop running for many millennia this could really add up! :D

Comment: New result is now up below (or above, depending on where it winds up).

Comment: yep, found it, thanks! linked to it from my answer. :) looove it! haven't played with it yet and am kinda tired, but I am thinking about porting yours to C# and seeing what kind of performance I can get there; also perhaps a version sacrificing some performance to make it more accessible to beginners. but *yawn* that will likely wait for another day. :) thanks again, I really appreciate how you spent so much time to make it a complete answer. ♡

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's code to take an arbitrary decimal number passed as the first arg and count down from it to zero.  I set it up to allow the counter to use different size elements (just change the typedef for COUNTER_BASE), but it turns out that bytes are actually somewhat faster than either short or long on my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>  // defines CHAR_BIT
#include <ctype.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
typedef unsigned char COUNTER_BASE;
typedef vector<COUNTER_BASE> COUNTER;
typedef vector<unsigned char> BYTEVEC;
const unsigned long byteMask = (~0ul) << CHAR_BIT;
const size_t MAXBYTES=20;

void mult10(BYTEVEC &val) {
    // Multiply value by 10
    unsigned int carry = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < val.size(); i++) {
        unsigned long value = val[i]*10ul+carry;
        carry = (value & byteMask) >> CHAR_BIT;
        val[i] = value & ~byteMask;
    }
    if (carry > 0) val.push_back(carry);
}

void addDigit(BYTEVEC &val, const char digit) {
    // Add digit to the number in BYTEVEC.
    unsigned int carry = digit - '0'; // Assumes ASCII char set
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < val.size() && carry; i++) {
        unsigned long value = static_cast<unsigned long>(val[i])+carry;
        carry = (value & byteMask) >> CHAR_BIT;
        val[i] = value & ~byteMask;
    }
    if (carry > 0) val.push_back(carry);
}

BYTEVEC Cstr2Bytevec(const char *str) {
    // Turn a C-style string into a BYTEVEC.  Only the digits in str apply,
    // so that one can use commas, underscores, or other non-digits to separate
    // digit groups.
    BYTEVEC result;
    result.reserve(MAXBYTES);
    result[0]=0;
    unsigned char *res=&result[0]; // For debugging
    while (*str) {
        if (isdigit(static_cast<int>(*str))) {
            mult10(result);
            addDigit(result, *str);
        }
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}

void packCounter(COUNTER &ctr, const BYTEVEC &val) {
    // Pack the bytes from val into the (possibly larger) datatype of COUNTER
    int i;
    ctr.erase(ctr.begin(), ctr.end());
    COUNTER_BASE value = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < val.size(); i++) {
        int pos = i%sizeof(COUNTER_BASE); // position of this byte in the value
        if (i > 0 && pos == 0) {
            ctr.push_back(value);
            value = val[i];
        } else {
            value |= static_cast<COUNTER_BASE>(val[i]) << pos*CHAR_BIT;
        }
    }
    ctr.push_back(value);
}

inline bool decrementAndTest(COUNTER &ctr) {
    // decrement value in ctr and return true if old value was not all zeros
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ctr.size() && !(ctr[i]--); i++) ; // EMPTY BODY
    return i < ctr.size();
}

inline bool decrementAndTest2(COUNTER_BASE *ctr, const size_t size) {
    // decrement value in ctr and return true if old value was not all zeros
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size && !(ctr[i]--); i++) ; // EMPTY BODY
    return i < size;
}

/* Vector counter - uses first arg (if supplied) as the count */
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    BYTEVEC limit = Cstr2Bytevec(argc > 1? argv[1] : "0");
    COUNTER ctr;
    packCounter(ctr, limit);
    COUNTER_BASE *ctr_vals = ctr.size() > 0 ? &ctr[0] : NULL; 
    size_t ctr_size = ctr.size();

    unsigned long ul_counter = 0ul; /* to give loop something to do */
    while(decrementAndTest2(ctr_vals, ctr_size)) {
        ul_counter++;
    };
    printf("With %d bytes used, final ul_counter value = %lu\n", limit.size(), ul_counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Examples of use:

$ time ./bigcounter 5

With 1 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 5

real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.047s

$ time ./bigcounter 5,000

With 2 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 5000

real    0m0.062s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.062s

$ time ./bigcounter 5,000,000

With 3 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 5000000

real    0m0.093s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./bigcounter 1,000,000,000

With 4 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 1000000000

real    0m2.688s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time ./bigcounter 2,000,000,000

With 4 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 2000000000

real    0m5.125s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./bigcounter 3,000,000,000

With 4 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 3000000000

real    0m7.485s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.047s

$ time ./bigcounter 4,000,000,000

With 4 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 4000000000

real    0m9.875s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./bigcounter 5,000,000,000

With 5 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 705032704

real    0m12.594s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time ./bigcounter 6,000,000,000

With 5 bytes used, final ul_counter value = 1705032704

real    0m14.813s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.062s

Unwrapping the counter vector into C-style data structures (i.e., using decrementAndTest2 instead of decrementAndTest) sped things up by around 20-25%, but the code is still about twice as slow as my previous C program for similar-sized examples (around 4 billion).  This is with MS Visual C++ 6.0 as the compiler in release mode, optimizing for speed, on a 2GHz dual-core system, for both programs.  Inlining the decrementAndTest2 function definitely makes a big difference (around 12 sec. vs. 30 for the 5 billion loop), but I'll have to see whether physically inlining the code as I did in the C program can get similar performance.

Comment: +1 Awesome. I haven't had a chance to play with it yet, but I love how you turned it into a complete solution. This is a terrific answer to the question, because it shows so much at once: 1. the inner workings of a multi-byte counter 2. the conversion of a number into a binary integer manually 3. that even simple ideas have more choices and trade-offs than you would think 4. analysis and optimization of inner-loop functionality and 5. that an algorithm that needs a loop of <huge num> iterations is kinda silly because there's just not enough time. (and more I'm sure) :) thanks dewtell! ♡

Answer (score 0):

**the variable in main function can Store even 100 factorial**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>

using namespace std;


//template for BIGINIT

// base and base_digits must be consistent
const int base = 10;
const int base_digits = 1;

struct bigint {
    vector<int> a;
    int sign;

    bigint() :
        sign(1) {
    }

    bigint(long long v) {
        *this = v;
    }

    bigint(const string &s) {
        read(s);
    }

    void operator=(const bigint &v) {
        sign = v.sign;
        a = v.a;
    }

    void operator=(long long v) {
        sign = 1;
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -1, v = -v;
        for (; v > 0; v = v / base)
            a.push_back(v % base);
    }

    bigint operator+(const bigint &v) const {
        if (sign == v.sign) {
            bigint res = v;

            for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int) max(a.size(), v.a.size()) || carry; ++i) {
                if (i == (int) res.a.size())
                    res.a.push_back(0);
                res.a[i] += carry + (i < (int) a.size() ? a[i] : 0);
                carry = res.a[i] >= base;
                if (carry)
                    res.a[i] -= base;
            }
            return res;
        }
        return *this - (-v);
    }

    bigint operator-(const bigint &v) const {
        if (sign == v.sign) {
            if (abs() >= v.abs()) {
                bigint res = *this;
                for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int) v.a.size() || carry; ++i) {
                    res.a[i] -= carry + (i < (int) v.a.size() ? v.a[i] : 0);
                    carry = res.a[i] < 0;
                    if (carry)
                        res.a[i] += base;
                }
                res.trim();
                return res;
            }
            return -(v - *this);
        }
        return *this + (-v);
    }

    void operator*=(int v) {
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -sign, v = -v;
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int) a.size() || carry; ++i) {
            if (i == (int) a.size())
                a.push_back(0);
            long long cur = a[i] * (long long) v + carry;
            carry = (int) (cur / base);
            a[i] = (int) (cur % base);
            //asm("divl %%ecx" : "=a"(carry), "=d"(a[i]) : "A"(cur), "c"(base));
        }
        trim();
    }

    bigint operator*(int v) const {
        bigint res = *this;
        res *= v;
        return res;
    }

    friend pair<bigint, bigint> divmod(const bigint &a1, const bigint &b1) {
        int norm = base / (b1.a.back() + 1);
        bigint a = a1.abs() * norm;
        bigint b = b1.abs() * norm;
        bigint q, r;
        q.a.resize(a.a.size());

        for (int i = a.a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            r *= base;
            r += a.a[i];
            int s1 = r.a.size() <= b.a.size() ? 0 : r.a[b.a.size()];
            int s2 = r.a.size() <= b.a.size() - 1 ? 0 : r.a[b.a.size() - 1];
            int d = ((long long) base * s1 + s2) / b.a.back();
            r -= b * d;
            while (r < 0)
                r += b, --d;
            q.a[i] = d;
        }

        q.sign = a1.sign * b1.sign;
        r.sign = a1.sign;
        q.trim();
        r.trim();
        return make_pair(q, r / norm);
    }

    bigint operator/(const bigint &v) const {
        return divmod(*this, v).first;
    }

    bigint operator%(const bigint &v) const {
        return divmod(*this, v).second;
    }

    void operator/=(int v) {
        if (v < 0)
            sign = -sign, v = -v;
        for (int i = (int) a.size() - 1, rem = 0; i >= 0; --i) {
            long long cur = a[i] + rem * (long long) base;
            a[i] = (int) (cur / v);
            rem = (int) (cur % v);
        }
        trim();
    }

    bigint operator/(int v) const {
        bigint res = *this;
        res /= v;
        return res;
    }

    int operator%(int v) const {
        if (v < 0)
            v = -v;
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            m = (a[i] + m * (long long) base) % v;
        return m * sign;
    }

    void operator+=(const bigint &v) {
        *this = *this + v;
    }
    void operator-=(const bigint &v) {
        *this = *this - v;
    }
    void operator*=(const bigint &v) {
        *this = *this * v;
    }
    void operator/=(const bigint &v) {
        *this = *this / v;
    }

    bool operator<(const bigint &v) const {
        if (sign != v.sign)
            return sign < v.sign;
        if (a.size() != v.a.size())
            return a.size() * sign < v.a.size() * v.sign;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (a[i] != v.a[i])
                return a[i] * sign < v.a[i] * sign;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator>(const bigint &v) const {
        return v < *this;
    }
    bool operator<=(const bigint &v) const {
        return !(v < *this);
    }
    bool operator>=(const bigint &v) const {
        return !(*this < v);
    }
    bool operator==(const bigint &v) const {
        return !(*this < v) && !(v < *this);
    }
    bool operator!=(const bigint &v) const {
        return *this < v || v < *this;
    }

    void trim() {
        while (!a.empty() && !a.back())
            a.pop_back();
        if (a.empty())
            sign = 1;
    }

    bool isZero() const {
        return a.empty() || (a.size() == 1 && !a[0]);
    }

    bigint operator-() const {
        bigint res = *this;
        res.sign = -sign;
        return res;
    }

    bigint abs() const {
        bigint res = *this;
        res.sign *= res.sign;
        return res;
    }

    long long longValue() const {
        long long res = 0;
        for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            res = res * base + a[i];
        return res * sign;
    }

    friend bigint gcd(const bigint &a, const bigint &b) {
        return b.isZero() ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
    friend bigint lcm(const bigint &a, const bigint &b) {
        return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
    }

    void read(const string &s) {
        sign = 1;
        a.clear();
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < (int) s.size() && (s[pos] == '-' || s[pos] == '+')) {
            if (s[pos] == '-')
                sign = -sign;
            ++pos;
        }
        for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= pos; i -= base_digits) {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = max(pos, i - base_digits + 1); j <= i; j++)
                x = x * 10 + s[j] - '0';
            a.push_back(x);
        }
        trim();
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream &stream, bigint &v) {
        string s;
        stream >> s;
        v.read(s);
        return stream;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, const bigint &v) {
        if (v.sign == -1)
            stream << '-';
        stream << (v.a.empty() ? 0 : v.a.back());
        for (int i = (int) v.a.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            stream << setw(base_digits) << setfill('0') << v.a[i];
        return stream;
    }

    static vector<int> convert_base(const vector<int> &a, int old_digits, int new_digits) {
        vector<long long> p(max(old_digits, new_digits) + 1);
        p[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < (int) p.size(); i++)
            p[i] = p[i - 1] * 10;
        vector<int> res;
        long long cur = 0;
        int cur_digits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) a.size(); i++) {
            cur += a[i] * p[cur_digits];
            cur_digits += old_digits;
            while (cur_digits >= new_digits) {
                res.push_back(int(cur % p[new_digits]));
                cur /= p[new_digits];
                cur_digits -= new_digits;
            }
        }
        res.push_back((int) cur);
        while (!res.empty() && !res.back())
            res.pop_back();
        return res;
    }

    typedef vector<long long> vll;

    static vll karatsubaMultiply(const vll &a, const vll &b) {
        int n = a.size();
        vll res(n + n);
        if (n <= 32) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    res[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
            return res;
        }

        int k = n >> 1;
        vll a1(a.begin(), a.begin() + k);
        vll a2(a.begin() + k, a.end());
        vll b1(b.begin(), b.begin() + k);
        vll b2(b.begin() + k, b.end());

        vll a1b1 = karatsubaMultiply(a1, b1);
        vll a2b2 = karatsubaMultiply(a2, b2);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            a2[i] += a1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            b2[i] += b1[i];

        vll r = karatsubaMultiply(a2, b2);
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) a1b1.size(); i++)
            r[i] -= a1b1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) a2b2.size(); i++)
            r[i] -= a2b2[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) r.size(); i++)
            res[i + k] += r[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) a1b1.size(); i++)
            res[i] += a1b1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) a2b2.size(); i++)
            res[i + n] += a2b2[i];
        return res;
    }

    bigint operator*(const bigint &v) const {
        vector<int> a6 = convert_base(this->a, base_digits, 6);
        vector<int> b6 = convert_base(v.a, base_digits, 6);
        vll a(a6.begin(), a6.end());
        vll b(b6.begin(), b6.end());
        while (a.size() < b.size())
            a.push_back(0);
        while (b.size() < a.size())
            b.push_back(0);
        while (a.size() & (a.size() - 1))
            a.push_back(0), b.push_back(0);
        vll c = karatsubaMultiply(a, b);
        bigint res;
        res.sign = sign * v.sign;
        for (int i = 0, carry = 0; i < (int) c.size(); i++) {
            long long cur = c[i] + carry;
            res.a.push_back((int) (cur % 1000000));
            carry = (int) (cur / 1000000);
        }
        res.a = convert_base(res.a, 6, base_digits);
        res.trim();
        return res;
    }
};
 //use :  bigint var;
//template for biginit over





int main()
{  
   bigint var=10909000890789;
   cout<<var;
return 0;
}
```